# Writing To Multiple TCP Ports From A Print Monitor

Tags: printing, drivers

I have a language monitor that I am trying to query the printer from.

First let me apologize for the possible confusion since "port" means 2 things in this description. There is the one use that refers to the port that the printer is configured to use, which could be TCP, USB, etc. And then there is the use of port that refers to the port address to send data to when communicating with the printer's IP address.

I need to be able to specify different port addresses to send different custom queries to a printer over the same IP that are specific to it's firmware. I can't find any examples or documentation on what the standard way is to do this communication... I can extract the IP address and open a net socket, but I am not sure if this is the appropriate way to handle this communication. It's not uncommon for printers to send status over one port, and print data over another. If i want to write to the Default port I can use pfnWritePort and pfnReadPort, but these don't allow me to specify the actual port.. it uses whatever the driver is configured as.

Can anyone provide some guidance or examples of how I should do this from my language monitor?

EDIT: As an example for clarification, all commands are sent to the same IP, but depending on the command/query I need to send, the TCP port needs to change. The way I am handling it now is opening up a net socket with the same IP and different port numbers for data and status channels).

Comment: You should define platform in clear way, windows is implied by those id's? You confuse yourself with port word. The former lemma you mean is a is NEVER to be called a port, it's an interface. Windows GUI architecture though uses term port to describe referred virtual interface for printer. The latter is "a number of TCP port"

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please read the [introduction tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to provide good example guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've only worked a small amount in windows driver development and mostly using existing projects as examples. My apologies about the term confusion and lack of definition. Some of it is that i'm unfamiliar with what technologies i'm working with in order to define. Your assumptions are correct Swift. I will refer to them as Virtual Interface (Windows Port) and TCP Port in my future responses to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be required to write an app that would be able to reconfigure driver. Ideology of OS is that EACH real device would corresponds to instance of driver and\or interface. Which might be an elevated action, because it requires to create new printer interface("port" in Windows  GUI terms) and change driver settings.

Comment: To make sure I am understanding you correctly, are you stating that a single driver instance should never communicate with each real device, and an external application should be managing creation and configuration of those instances so they can be used collectively for communication?

Can you clarify what is meant as a real device? All communication is going to the same device and connection, just down different channels to the same IP (in this case TCP ports) depending on what the command/query is, and that's what the driver - specifically the print monitor - needs to know and route.

Comment: @Christopher Whittier language monitor's purpose isn't routing .. it's conversion of data between  spool and port monitor. And why you would have such setup. Oh, there was thing like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/combined-language-and-port-monitor

Comment: The print monitor provides a SendRecvBidiDataFromPort function who's purpose is to facilitate communication with the printer for default and custom queries. Things like ink levels and printer status can be queried in this way. Again I stress that it is very common for devices to handle different queries/responses over different ports. A data channel, a status channel, etc. No configuration is required, however the language monitor or the port monitor (let's assume they are combined) should have the knowledge of how to perform those queries, which involves knowing which channel to use.

Comment: The question is less about which layer is responsible for the routing decision, and more about the proper way to send TCP/IP data from the print monitor over the desired port. If the answer is that it shouldn't be done, then how is it possible to support status from printers who operate in this function via the windows GDI driver interface?